Athena Unload command does not specify correct metadata
In Athena, when using the unload command to output text files to an s3 location such as:
UNLOAD (SELECT * FROM some_view)
TO 's3://results_folder/some_run/'
WITH (
    format = 'textfile',
    compression='GZIP'
);

The outputted files do not have the correct metadata set.
Expected metadata:
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain
Actual metadata:
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
This means that other applications that use this data do not receive it as uncompressed data and may not know how to handle it. For instance, importing those files into postrgres using aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 fails with the original metadata but works correctly when the expected metadata is set.
You can manually set the metadata but that means you have to copy the original file, which kind of defeats the purpose of having the data in the format you need where you need it, which is what unload does.
Can i use some configuration option so the correct metadata is set?
